# Docker copy not work, content not updated

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I try to configure docker with php(symfony app).

When I build container for first time, symfony skeleton app appears in container, but any other builds sasdoes not change anything inside container.

Dockefile

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN rm ./etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx/site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
COPY . /var/www/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  simple-app-symfony:
    image: simple-app-symfony
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - php 
    volumes:
      - data:/var/www/html
  php:
    image: php:7.1-fpm
    volumes:
      - data:/var/www/html
volumes:
  data:
```

nginx/site.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name ~.;

    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   try_files $uri =404;
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    #}

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            internal;
        }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }

}
```

I tried docker-compose build --no-cache, docker build . -t simple-app-symfony -> nothing changes. 
Any ideas whats going on?
I think that the problem is with volumes, because it I removed volume's secition, the container has been updated.

But I need volumes mapping, because in this case, php needs to have access, to source code

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the contents of `/var/www/html` in two conflicting steps:

1. The `COPY` instruction in Dockerfile copies files in build context to container's `/var/www/html` folder.
2. The volume mounting instruction in docker-compose mounts a volume to the same folder, which makes the copied files invisible.

To fix this, remove the `COPY` instruction in Dockerfile, and use bind-mount in docker-compose to mount you source code folder to container's `/var/www/html`.

Comment: Ok, your solution will works, but what if I want to have my source code copied inside container, instead mount volume each time?